# How to get a one click downloadable csv/excel file from a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, download

I have a mysql connection open and want to export all the data into a downloadable csv or excel file. I suspect that it has something to do with Select (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) but cannot get together syntax that works. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: start with a basic php and mysql tutorial

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your csv generating code and we will give you some direction.

Comment: CSV can be done as @alex has said in his answer. For a genuine Excel file, you'll need to use a library like PHPExcel ( http://www.phpexcel.net )

Answer (score 0):

I saw this for the first time the other day, and it is pretty awesome.

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "/csvs/my-csv.cvs"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
FROM whatever;
```

Then link them to `/csvs/my-csv.cvs`, or force a download with PHP.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/csv');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');

readfile('/csvs/my-csv.csv');

exit;
```

Comment: @RDL I have not been able to get the above code to work. I have been using this:   $FileName = "/googleresearch" .  abs(rand(0,1000000000000))  .  ".csv";

$query = "SELECT * FROM happyturtle INTO OUTFILE $FileName;
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"';
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

exit;

Comment: Ok I have a question on this as well. My code that I have works perfectly to download on my localhost but when I upload it to a test server I get error messages saying the header information has already been sent any ideas?